# How to provide syntax highlighting in common editors for a DSL specified in an ANTLR grammar?

Tags: antlr4, syntax-highlighting

My team develops a DSL used by hundreds of customers who prefer a variety of editors. We would like to support syntax highlighting in multiple common editors, which seems like a common need for language maintainers, but I'm failing to find any description of standard practices.

Our DSL grammar is specified in ANTLR, and we are most interested in VSCode, Vim, and IntelliJ, but of course the list goes on. It seems like once a grammar has been specified, portable syntax highlighting should come more or less for free - just specify a declarative map from symbols to syntactic labels.

1. Is there an easy way to produce multi-editor syntax highlighting from our grammar definition?
2. If not, I assume we need to manually integrate with each editor from scratch. This sounds like a maintenance headache. How do modern languages handle this problem? (Also, why is this needed? What makes highlighting as a function of a grammar a hard problem to solve in a reusable way?)

Comment: The usual solution nowadays is to write an LSP server that does parsing, builds a symbol table, and handles requests. Returning information about semantic highlighting is kind of tedious. A CFG is insufficient. You need expressions to pick off symbols after a parse.

Comment: @kaby76 agreed CFG is insufficient, but mapping symbols to syntax highlighting labels seems like a declarative programming task. If I want interactive editing features, sure, an LSP is a good solution, but it seems very heavy-weight just for syntax highlighting. Am I missing something?

Comment: Perhaps the reality is that most language maintainers with resources to support highlighting in multiple editors also have the resources to support interactive editing. But even then, LSP doesn't sound like the typical solution:

(A) LSP only added highlighting in the last 3 years. What did people do before that?

(B) From the LSP issue threads, it looks like LSP assumes there is already syntactic highlighting in the LSP client, which will simply be augmented by LSP's semantic highlighting: https://github.com/microsoft/language-server-protocol/issues/1063

Comment: Most will want eventually go to refs and defs, hover, renaming, etc. There is nothing that takes a grammar and xpaths and outputs a textmate solution. Of course parse speed will depend on a good grammar.

Comment: Okay - but LSP only added highlighting 3 years ago. What did people do before that?

Comment: Use textmate if that is all you want.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is there an easy way to produce multi-editor syntax highlighting from our grammar definition?

As far as I know, there is no way to do that.

> 2. [...] What are best practices from people who have done this?

I've no experience creating multiple plugins, but that is a subjective question, and therefor not really suitable for stackoverflow. From the page "what questions to avoid":

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions [...]
>
> -- https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: Thanks @bart-kiers, I've updated the question to be narrow. The standard recommendations from a community of practice is not a topic for open-ended discussion - either there is a short list of competing options, or there is no consensus.